# Not able to perform post request django+react

Tags: python, django

```
#accounts.models.py:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from words import models as word_models

# Create your models here.class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete  = models.CASCADE)
    last_visited_word = models.ForeignKey(word_models.Word, default=4760, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:  
       profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)  

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User) 

#words/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


# Create your models here.

class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    meaning = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    
#accounts/serializers.py:
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import UserProfile


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
    
    
#accounts/views.py:
@api_view(['POST'])
  #@authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def userprofile_create_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user_id = request.data.get('user')
    try:
        instance = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        instance=None
    serializer = UserSerializer(instance, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        # create or update data
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

So Basically I have to update the last_visited_word of the user when the user visits that particular id. I am not able to do the "post" method to update last_visited_word. Api calling is done using axios. I am using React as my frontend. When I try to use the post request, it says a bad request. BTW react and django are connected as I am able to do a GET request successfully.

Comment: Hello, it is better to asked more detailed question. for an example, you can mention what are the errors you get. and some code snippet how would you sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

first of the question is kind of incomplete, but from what I can understand you need to configure your settings.py to allow post request from your react localhost. Also finding a way around Django and react can be quite tricky.

Answer (score 0):

check if the api is working as expected. also in the django setting enable cors in middleware and **whitelist the server on which the react is running.**

Comment: hey!, yes that i had already setup. I am able to pull off a "GET" but not able to do a "POST"

Comment: are you passing in the auth token from react. Also can you post your react code that might be of somehelp

Comment: no i am not using authtoken. i have serialized the userprofile. Using the serializer, i can access the current user. This is the format: {"id: 4, "user": 7, "last_visited_word": 4760}. i have to edit the "last_visited_word" using "POST". currently when i try to do post, drf says "user" field is required.

Comment: For updating the post you should use put call I believe. Using post would require the user field as well

Comment: yes, i realised that a while back. But since I have reactified django, whenever i do a put, it says forbidden. idk why

Comment: Maybe because you are using viewsets. I dont remember much of it now but using mixins to create api should do the work. Also @api_view(['POST']) will only take post requests

Comment: can you please elaborate as in how?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/